# Not able to calculate (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) correctly in MySQL innoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, information-schema

I'm using MySQL innoDB for storing data. I needed to restrict the size of a particular table by some value. Soo after inserting data to the table, i will check the (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) to see if it exceeded the limit. If exceeded i will delete some old data, until (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) will reach below the limit.

But i'm getting unexpected (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) value. so im not able to procced.
(i have explained the situation below)

Initially i have a table tableTime with (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) as around 15GB and DATA_FREE as 0GB. It has 2,000,000 rows.

```
DELETE FROM tableTime
LIMIT 1000000;
```

i deleted 1,000,000 rows (using above query)
then waited for mysqld.exe to complete the disk I/O (manually see through task manager) and rebooted the system also.

```
ANALYZE TABLE tableTime;
SELECT ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) AS TABLE_NAME  FROM information_schema.TABLES
where TABLE_NAME = 'tableTime';
```

now i checked (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) again (using above query) i found it as ~13GB and DATA_FREE as ~2GB.

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE tableTime;
SELECT ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) AS TABLE_NAME  FROM information_schema.TABLES
where TABLE_NAME = 'tableTime';
```

then i tried OPTIMIZE and got the expected like 8-9GB (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH).

But since tables are big i cant do OPTIMIZE every time to get table size. why ANALYZE is this much inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Data_length`, `index_length`, and `data_free` are not measuring what you think they're measuring.

InnoDB stores data and indexes on pages, which are 16KB by default and are uniform in size. Pages are grouped into extents of 1MB, i.e. 64 pages by default.

When you insert or update data to a tablespace, InnoDB may expand the tablespace. Initial expansion is done by small amounts, after which expansion occurs 4MB at a time (4 extents).

Each page stores at least 2 rows, and stores as many rows as fit in the page (long varchar/text/blob columns are stored on separate pages).

As you update or delete rows, this might leave gaps of unused space in a given page. Further inserts and updates attempts to use these gaps if possible, but in practice they tend to become fragmented, with lots of small pockets of wasted space.

Here's a thing you must understand: `data_free` measures only whole extents (64 pages) of unused space. This does not include the small pockets of wasted space. It doesn't even include empty pages, unless there are 64 contiguous empty pages. You might notice that `data_free` is always a multiple of 1MB.

The `data_length` and `index_length` measure the total size of the pages that are at least partially filled, not the size of the data in them.

This means that the actual size of data might be significantly less than what is reported by `data_length` + `index_length`.

So how can you get a precise measure of the actual space occupied by data and indexes?

**There's no command to measure precisely the size of data in an InnoDB table.**

It's a difficult value to pin down anyway, because of transactions and multi-versioning. If you delete a row but you haven't committed that transaction yet, should you count the space? Likewise, if you've inserted a row but not committed, does that space count? What about multiple versions of a give row? What about rows that exist only in modified pages in the buffer pool, but they haven't been flushed to disk yet?

Waiting for I/O to settle isn't reliable either, because InnoDB continues to do gradual updates, things like purging old row versions and merging the change buffer into secondary indexes. This can even continue *after a reboot*.

Even if you could measure the size of data that precisely, the measurement would be outdated in a fraction of a second, because many databases have frequent updates.

Comment: A Rule of Thumb:  An InnoDB table will be about 2x-3x the size predicted by adding up the datatype sizes (4 fir INT, 5 for TIMESTAMP, etc.)

Comment: @RickJames, sure, but that's not very precise either! :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer :).
So now i'm planning to monitor the growth of the table after every insertion and schedule OPTIMIZE if it exceed the limit. then i'll check the size again and take decision on deletion. hope this solution works to some extend.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how you started with 15GB but the first attempt left it at 15GB (13+2).  This is because `DELETE` does not free up any disk space, or at least does not give it back to the OS, hence `Data_length`, etc show no total difference.

`OPTIMIZE` will rebuild the table.  So, *if* `innodb_file_per_table = ON` when the table was [re]built, the space will be freed up.  Otherwise, as Bill points out, it will simply be left for future `INSERTs`

As you probably noticed, `DELETEing` a million rows is terribly slow.  You might want to consider several less-invasive ways, which I have compiled [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig)

Comment: Thank you for this answer :).
Soo there is any way to control the size of the table (```innodb_file_per_table = ON```) without OPTIMIZE ? . 
I have gone through the article  you mentioned, i felt like doing PARTITION will help. PARTITION by date as key. Then delete older partitions when whole table exceed the my limit. Also i'm not sure of the query performance after doing the partition.

Comment: @RishadC - Query performance is mostly unaffected by Partitioning.  Don't go past, say, 50 partitions.  Dropping one partition shrinks the table by 2%.  Meanwhile, 50 partitions incurs an overhead of about 300MB (see `SHOW TABLE STATUS`)

Comment: @RishadC - However, you must rethink all the indexes on the table.  Some may need revising to avoid performance degradation.  (For further advice, start a new query with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the main queries.)